# GhostScript "Unrecoverable error, exit code 1" when using embeded fonts in .pdf

Tags: linux, pdf, centos, ghostscript

I have been trying to convert a .pdf file to a .png in **Imagick**, but I keep getting the

> Unrecoverable error, exit code 1.

I did some research and discovered that the problem is somehow related to the embedded fonts in the .pdf file (the file can be opened in Adobe Reader and maybe every other application but not in GS).

I did some Googling around, but 2-3 hours later, gave up with no luck.
How can I fix it? Please help me out!

The machine on which I'm doing the tests is CentOS 6.3.
Ghostscript version - 8.70-15

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a version of Ghostscript which isn't quite so elderly. That version is 4 years old now, the current version is 9.07.

If current code fails in a similar fashion, then you can open a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com. If you do open a bug, remember to attach the specimen file and a command line to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did not know that a newer version existed, that did the trick! Thanks!